# Populate UIPickerView with items from class

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have the following class:

```
class JobItem {
    var ItemID:String = String()
    var Qty:Int = Int()
    var Item:String = String()
}
```

I also have a collection of items in this class like so:

```
 var jobitems: [JobItem] = []
```

I would like to populate my pickerview with just the Item part from each instance of the class in the array and I'm not sure how. I successfully filled it with data from a dummy array I created so it's working OK, just need that data in.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     return jobitems.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return  as? String
}
```

Comment: return jobitems[row]. Item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `titleForRow`, you just need to return the correct Item string with the correct row that can mapped to index of your array:

`return jobitems[row].Item`

Comment: Oh great, that's good to know I have the index already associated with it. Thanks

Comment: Its because you have the same number declared when you return `jobitems.count` in your `numberOfRowsInComponent`, if this number is not the same as your total `row`, you will get crash when you do this

Answer (score 0):

Just takeout element from array to your instance class & populate what you wants,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String {
    var titleFoRow: String? = nil
    var classObject: ModelClass? = nil
      classObject = self.arrayCountryList[row]
      self.titleFoRow = classObject.instanceVarName

    return self.titleFoRow
}
```